# How to Simplify .htaccess Rewriterule by 'RewriteCond' ?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my .htaccess is looks like this:

```
    #01
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/yule/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=2

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/yule/today/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=2&today=true
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/yule/today/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=2&today=true&order=$2&ordertype=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/yule/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=2&order=$2&ordertype=$3

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/yule_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=2&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/yule_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/today/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=2&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&today=true
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/yule_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/today/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=2&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&today=true&order=$4&ordertype=$5
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/yule_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=2&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&order=$4&ordertype=$5

#02
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/travel/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=3

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/travel/today/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=3&today=true
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/travel/today/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=3&today=true&order=$2&ordertype=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/travel/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=3&order=$2&ordertype=$3

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/travel_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=3&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/travel_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/today/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=3&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&today=true
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/travel_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/today/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=3&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&today=true&order=$4&ordertype=$5
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/travel_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=3&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&order=$4&ordertype=$5

#03
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/service/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=4

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/service/today/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=4&today=true
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/service/today/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=4&today=true&order=$2&ordertype=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/service/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=4&order=$2&ordertype=$3

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/service_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=4&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/service_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/today/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=4&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&today=true
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/service_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/today/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=4&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&today=true&order=$4&ordertype=$5
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/service_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=4&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&order=$4&ordertype=$5

#04
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/gou/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=5

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/gou/today/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=5&today=true
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/gou/today/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=5&today=true&order=$2&ordertype=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/gou/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=5&order=$2&ordertype=$3

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/gou_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=5&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/gou_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/today/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=5&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&today=true
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/gou_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/today/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=5&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&today=true&order=$4&ordertype=$5
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/gou_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=5&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&order=$4&ordertype=$5

#05
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/qita/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=6

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/qita/today/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=6&today=true
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/qita/today/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=6&today=true&order=$2&ordertype=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/qita/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=6&order=$2&ordertype=$3

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/qita_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=6&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/qita_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/today/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=6&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&today=true
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/qita_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/today/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=6&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&today=true&order=$4&ordertype=$5
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/qita_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/(price|rebate|bought)_(desc|asc)/ index.php?city=$1&category=6&price_sta=$2&price_end=$3&order=$4&ordertype=$5

#06
#07
#08
... ...
```

I have many categories, such as:'yule','travel','service','gou','qita',~~~~many categorys~~~~~~ These categories correspond to id like this: 'meishi' -> category=1 'yule' ->category=2 'travel' ->category=3 'service'->category=4 'gou' ->category=5 'qita' ->category=6 ~~~~~~~ How to simplify these categorys Using 'RewriteCond' ?

Comment: I think you are looking for RewriteMap, where the rule would fetch the url-slug for the provided ID. Am I right?

Comment: I do not have the experience to write  RewriteMap.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the docs about Rewrite Mapping: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html

Your goal here is to map a human-readable category slug to a category number, by means of a text file.

For example, if you were to input `/travel` as your URL, the mapper would consult the text file and return `3` for the category

So, `([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)` would become `index.php?city=$1&category=${examplemap:$1|/404.php}`.
For example, `mycity/travel` would become `index.php?city=mycity&category=3` after the lookup/map.

Then, using your rewrite rules, you would not need to repeat all of them for every category.

If you have difficulty with the documentation, let me know and I will try to put something together for you.